# Using Button Click to Update Values Returned from Firestore in For Loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, button, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a basic CRUD site that I started working on recently to list a number of products and the associated prices. My skills aren't the best but I am fighting the good fight and would like some assistance/guidance with what I am trying to achieve.

I have data stored in a Firestore database and I have it being pulled and shown in a list. In order to display it I have the values in my sub-collection being added to an array and then I am using a for loop to loop through and pull each value and display it using an html template string. I decided that since I have the create and display aspect of this to a decent point, I would like to add a button (or in my case an icon) that would allow me edit each value that is returned.

```
    const shelf = doc.data();
    doc.ref.collection("products").get().then((Snapshot) => {
        const products = Snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());


        // start of for loop
        for(let product of products){

        // start of template string inside backticks
        const li = `
            <p><div>${product.name} <div class="right"><font class=pink-text>Price:</font> $${product.price}  <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-priceedit"><i class="material-icons">create</i></a></div></div></p>
        `;
        // end of template string inside backticks  

        html += li;                 


        // start of edit price section
        let price = product.price;                  

        const priceeditForm = document.querySelector('#priceedit-form');
        priceeditForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

            console.log("Document with ID: ", doc.id);
            doc.ref.collection("vendors").doc(price)get().then((Snapshot) => {
                const priceedit = Snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
             price: priceeditForm['price'].value

            }).then(() => {
            // close the signup modal & reset form
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-priceedit');
            M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
            priceeditForm.reset();
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
        });
        //end of edit price section 


        }
       // end of for loop           


        productList.innerHTML = html;           
        });
```

I would like that when the icon is clicked, that a model pops up with a single input fields for the price and I can enter the new price and submit it, hence updating the value in the database.

I will be very grateful to anyone who can assist me with this. Thank you in advance.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX4W4.png)

Comment: Can you double check the code formatting remained intact? For example, It looks as though some of the data is aligned such that the for loop only prints 4 `console.log`s and then ends.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The console.log was just there so I can make sure that it was pulling the values I needed. So the for loop takes the array called products that was returned ( [{name, price}, {name, price}] ) and then pulls the values from it and adds the values inside the html as it loops around  ${product.name} Price:$${product.price}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who assisted on this. I decided to redo my code from scratch using DOM elements to appendChild. Once done this made everything sooooo much easier. Decided to change it to give myself more flexibility with the code.